# How to configure lazy or incremental build in general with Ant?

Tags: gwt, ant, build-process, build-automation

Java compiler provides incremental build, so *javac* ant task as well. But most other processes don't.

Considering build processes, they transform some set of files (source) into another set of files (target).

I can distinct two cases here:

1. Transformator **cannot** take a subset of source files, only the whole set. Here we can only make **lazy build** - if no files from source was modified - we skip processing.
2. Transformator **can** take a subset of sources files and produce a partial result - **incremental build**.

What are ant internal, third-party extensions or other tools to implement lazy and incremental build?
Can you provide some widespread buildfile examples?

I am interested this to work with GWT compiler in particular.

Answer (score 5):

The [uptodate](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html) task is Ant's generic solution to this problem. It's flexible enough to work in most situations where lazy or incremental compilation is desirable.

I had the same problem as you: I have a GWT module as part of my code, and I don't want to pay the (hefty!) cost of recompiling it when I don't need to. The solution in my case looked something like this:

```
<uptodate property="gwtCompile.mymodule.notRequired"
  targetfile="www/com.example.MyGwtModule/com.example.MyGwtModule.nocache.js">
    <srcfiles dir="src" includes="**"/>
</uptodate>

<target name="compile-mymodule-gwt" unless="gwtCompile.mymodule.notRequired">
    <compile-gwt-module module="com.example.MyGwtModule"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Related to GWT, it's not possible to do incremental builds because the GWT compiler looks at all the source code at once and optimizes and inlines code. This means code that wasn't changed could be evaluated differently, for example if you start using a method from a class that wasn't changed, the method was in the previous compilation step left out, but now needs to be compiled in.

Comment: But surely it could be possible that NO code that affects the output of a GWT module has changed, and hence the module would not need re-compiling. Changes that affect the output be anything included in the <inherits> tree

Comment: @Andrew No, not necessary. Because the GWT compiler removes all code not used. So if you start using a method from that module it wouldn't be available. Also because inline optimization happens before the actual JavaScript is generated. Maybe it would be possible to cache intermediate results, but I'm not sure if that would be efficient, because those results need to interpreted again and read/written to disk, instead of keeping it in memory.

Comment: But if no Java source (that is used to generate JS output) has changed since last compile, then there is no need to recompile anything, optimizations and inlining and code removal included.....