# Is there a way to run a target only if a file has been changed since the last build?

Tags: ant, build-process

In an ant build script, is there a way to check if the files in one folder have been changed or added to since the last build, and then conditionally run a target based on that check?

My project has three `assets` folders, one for each of three platforms, which the main Java app pulls from when it runs. I have one `etc` folder with the raw versions of the files, where I make changes that need to be propagated to the three `assets` folders.

I have a target that packs the images and copies the files over. It is going to take longer and longer to run this target as the project grows in size, so I would only like this target to run when there's been a change in the `etc` folder since the last time it was run.

My first thought was to compare the date created/modified values between `etc` and one of the `assets` folders, which works for files simply copied over. For the packed images, it could check all the images in `etc` and get the most recent created/modified date, and see if that's newer than the packed image files in `assets`.

But I don't know how to implement this in an ant build script. Is there a built-in way to do this? If not, are there easy-to-import tools to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure lazy or incremental build in general with Ant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216279/how-to-configure-lazy-or-incremental-build-in-general-with-ant)